# Customize Voronoi tesselation to match a specific radii probability distribution of equi sized circles

Tags: probability-distributions, voronoi-diagram

I'm trying to generate an artificial grain structure for simulation purposes. Therefore I used a Voronoi tesselation. It didn't look bad but when I looked into details, some parts did not satisfy.

When plotting a histogram of the area-sizes of the Voronoi mesh that are 100% within specified borders, the results will be a lognormal distribution. Plotting the radius of equisized circles of those areas, the result is a normal distribution.

In reality, this is not the case. In reality the area probability function is also lognormal but much wider. For Voronoi, the ratio between the peak and maximum value is like 2.5-3, but in reality this ratio is more like 6-7, which results that even the radii distribution, which is ~sqrt(A), is a lognormal distribution instead of a normal distribution as in the voronoi case.

I tried very much to get a Voronoi tesselation where the radii distribution matches my desired lognormal distribution.

My best results so far, was done by packing random sized spheres (between a minimum and maximum radius) in a specific area, which will results in a hyperbolic size distribution, and to use those seeds as input for the Voronoi tesselation. With this technique the results look like this:

[Spheres in Area for Voronoi seed input:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJZdi.png)

[Voronoi tesselation of sphere seeds:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXZhx.jpg)

The problem now is following: The Voronoi algorithm draws the normal half way the connecting line between the lines connecting the seeds (I know its connecting the middle points of the spheres from Delaunay). Since that half way split is not the same point where the original spheres touched, original large spheres become smaller and original small spheres become larger polygons, but the worst part is that, since a large sphere has many neighbours in most cases, that the Voronoi polygons of those neighbours are stretched in radius direction of the large sphere due to the fact that small spheres come enlarged polygons and larger ones become smaller ones.

To compensate for the size discrepancy between spheres and Voronoi I have to use larger spheres then intended to compensate the "Voronoi shrink" of the larger ones which leads even more to this tendency of polygon stretching.

You can see this in my example picture below:

[Example picture of polygon stretching near large neighbours:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZhZZ.png)

This can also be observed in my second image, the Voronoi tesselation. The smaller poygons beneath the largest ones always tend to have a distinct shape anisotropy along the radius of the large grains and this is not intended to be. I want a Voronoi mesh, matching my desired distribution but the mesh itself should be homogeneous without any shape anisotropy or any clustering.

Does anybody has an idea how to modify my resent approach or a totally different approach which leads to the desired result? Maybe just some hinds how to proceed since it seems to be not a trivial problem.

Comment: Bringing the comment from the other site: For voronoi meshes, if you require a cell to be regular (e.g. a pentagon/hexagon) then your only option is to tile the plane with the same size (not all are valid). If you change the size even once, then you will forcefully generate "anysotropic shapes". Can you clarify what is a valid or invalid mesh anysotropy in your case?

Comment: From the materials science side of view I would say that shape anisotropy ia subjective impression. I would kinf of express it like follwoing: fitting an ellipse on the cell the ratio of the two radi should not exeed a factor of like 2, maybe 2.5. I would need to know what the factor of this elongated cells around the lareger ones would be, but whatever factor it would be, its to high, the shape should be more globular, while it does not have to be a regular hexagon/pentagon

Comment: Or lets say I'm finde with the shape, whatever ratio it would be, but im not glad about that circular  radial arangement of them, thats more my problem,

Comment: Thanks! Can you describe that specifically? Like, write a metric that we can measure if we had a particular voronoi cell?

Comment: To get away from the ellipse fit, i would say min(caliber-diameter)/max(caliper-diameter) should be between betwwen 0.4 to 2.5. About the radial arrangement: I would measure the angle between x or y axis and the direction of max(caliper-diameter) and would say that cells which share at least 1 vertice, that angle must differ by lets say 30°. Are that the kind of metrics you wanted?

Comment: I don't know, just trying to help you be more specific so you get better help ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you construct the [Power Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram) (which is closely related to the Voronoi diagram), you can associated weights to the vertices of the diagram and the boundaries between the cells are shifted according to the relative weights. In your case, you can weight your cells by the size of the circles/spheres that you are packing and you should get the result you are looking for.

One implementation of this is in CGAL (called regular triangulation which is the dual generalization of the Delaunay triangulation): you can see an example specifying weights with the vertices [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title22).

If you look Figure 7 (below) from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273284325_Modeling_of_Spherical_Particle_Packing_Structures_Using_Mathematical_Tessellation) Larysa Burtseva
by Frank Werner shows the power diagram in a situation very similar to yours.

[image: Example Power Diagram]

Comment: I will have a closer look at it but from a quick overview it looks indeed quite similar to my problem, or lets say she had ta very similar purpose and came up with the solution i was looking for.Thank you

Comment: Could you give me an additionla tip about the weights? I took the cicrle centers of pic 1 as seeds and the radi as weights, but that doenst work out. Also in some simpler examples that i tried its more tricky than that. When one point has the weight 1 and the other the weight 2 (like 2 cirlcles , one with hlaf the radius of the other) the seperation lie is not drawn at 2/3 of the distance.. How can i calculate the weights that would draw the line at 2/3 the disatcne when one circle has radius 2 and the other 1, because the radius is the wrong weight here as it seems?

Comment: I think using the radii as the weights is exactly what you want. For tangent circles, the [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) that separates the cells of the  power diagram is the line of tangency of  the circles. For non-overlapping circles, the line is always somewhere between the two circles. But it isn't exactly the ratio of the weights. If points have radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ and are a distance $1$ apart, the relative distance to the first point is $\frac{1 + r_1^2 - r_2^2}{2}$. What software are you using to compute the power diagram?

Comment: Somebody wrote it for MatLab and you can download it, Voronoi is  MatLab build in, Power not, but as i said, somebody wrote it on you can download the code. It works so far, but i still dont get my desire distribution, bu thats because the initial distribution from sphere packing in the square is wrong. The probability for each sphere between min and max radius is the same(uniform distribution). But the more spheres i place in the square, the probability that a larg sphere fits in unoccupied space drops. Thats why the size distribution is has a 1/x shape rather than uniform.

Comment: Which initial distribution for sphere radi selection would i need that in the end the size distribution would be a lognormal instead of 1/x-shape?

Comment: I would expect the packing shown in your [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJZdi.png) to give a nice power diagram: the cell boundaries should all lie in between the circles shown. I would suspect something wrong building or interpreting the power diagram rather than an issue with the waits selected in that situation.